# How to handle bias in this case?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, descriptive-statistics, bias

I've real world data of withdrawals on policies, as you can see in the image below, max withdrawals are done during great recession (2008-2010).

we must treat this as outliers, right ?

what is the best approach in this case, if want to use this data for simple Machine learning task to predict the probability of partial withdrawal on policy ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe an outlier, but a **real** data point, beware of just throwing it out!  If you do that , you build a model which are simply assuming that such rapid change is impossible, which is clearly not true.

Comment: Perhaps you might consider models based on heavy-tailed distributions or robust statistical methods.